# Form submitted via dialog opens dialog again

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form in a jquerymobile dialog box that I am submitting via jQuery Ajax.

Currently my problem is that once the form is submitted the same dialog box is opened again on top of the original dialogbox.

So that my url reads before submission:

```
url/index.php#&ui-state=dialog
```

and then after submission:

```
url/index.php#&ui-state=dialog#&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog
```

Has anyone ever encountered something like this before?

[edit added code example]

```
$(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataString = $("#form").serialize();
    errorInput = $("input[name=valOne]#valOne").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "formHandler.php",
            data: dataString,
        dataType: "text",
            success: function(data){
            if(data.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") >= 0){
                alert(data);
                $(".ui-dialog").dialog("close");
                $("#valOne").val(errorInput);  //the reentering info so user doesn't have to
            }else{
                    $(".ui-dialog").dialog("close");
                    location.href="index.php";
            }
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm still running into this problem if anyone had an idea.

Comment: I realized that some code was missing, I've added it in, hopefully that will give a better idea of whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set your own handler on form with this [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)
2. Use two forms for page and for your dialog window.

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to mention that I am already handling the form with `.submit()` and when a success response is received that `$(".ui-dialog").dialog("close")` is kicked in, which should close the dialog window, but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using $.mobile.changePage("url here") instead of location.href?
More details here http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: That works, thanks, but what if I were to change the success response like so, how would I keep the dialog from opening again and ensure that the input changes in the original dialog and not the copy that was opened over the original?  

`success: function(data){
 if(data.toLowerCase().indexOf("error") >= 0){
  alert(data);
  $("input[name=username]").val(errorUser);  //errorUser set before Ajax is run
 }else{
  $(".ui-dialog").dialog("close");
  location.href="index.php";
 }
},`

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your comment. Are you asking how can you ensure that when you open the dialog again it will not have the previous values in the form? If that's what you are asking you can solve it by resetting the dialog's form: $("#form")[0].reset() in the success callback before changing the page.

Comment: Part of the problem I'm having is that when the Ajax script runs successfully the dialog window opens again on top of itself (as seen in the URL above) and the value of the variable I mentioned is then applied to the new/replicated dialog box. You then have two dialogs to close as opposed to. just one.

Comment: I understood from your first comment that using $.mobile.changePage had solved the problem of the dialog reopening. Was that not the case?

Comment: Sorry, no, it did fix the redirection issue though.

Comment: Sorry, I've added some code that was missing, which may have been part of all the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be easier to just refresh the page with JS instead of loading it again? It might be calling the dialog functions twice.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with forms. I decided to use `<div data-role="fieldcontain">` instead. Now it works good with no "refresh effect". In this case you shouldmake your own message instead of .serialize.

Comment: Avoiding the user of serialize didn't have any effect, you used `<div data-role="fieldcontain">` instead of `<form>`?

Comment: Yes. There is a problem with form. I made fieldcontain, and a button. On button's click, I make a simple ajax call with message dynamically prepared earlier.